# Section formatting: text/ornament after and before within the title

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I would like to do redefine the section title command by enclosing it with ornaments like the following:

~ornament~ **SectionTitle** ~ornament~

I had looked up the `titlesec` documentation and many more example on how to redefine titles without any clues on how to add text after the title.

The aim is to add text in the section title after the `\thesection` command.

tldr;

I find out how to redefine `\section` to do that:

~ornament~ **SectionTitle**

but not how to do that:

~ornament~ **SectionTitle** ~ornament~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last mandatory argument of `\titlesec` may end with a one argument command, which the title is passed to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
 {\Large\bfseries}
 {\thesection}
 {1em}
 {\makeornament}

\newcommand{\makeornament}[1]{$\clubsuit$~#1\unskip~$\clubsuit$}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\section*{Unnumbered section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you both for your answers that was exactly what I wanted ! I prefer _egreg_'s answer which is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to be what you're after; you can redefine `\secornament` to be/use whatever you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\secornament}{$\clubsuit$}
\newcommand{\secornamentstyle}{}

\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{ s o m }{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldsection*{\secornamentstyle{#3}}}% \section*{...}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
       {\oldsection[#2]{\secornamentstyle{#3}}}% \section[..]{...}
       {\oldsection[#3]{\secornamentstyle{#3}}}% \section{...}
    }%
}

\begin{document}

% Keep \secornamentstyle to do nothing, otherwise \tableofcontents would set
% \section*{Contents} using the ornaments
\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\secornamentstyle}[1]{\secornament~#1~\secornament}
\section{A section}
\section*{Unnumbered section}

\end{document}
```

`\section` is redefined using [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse) for ease of distinguishing between the optional starred `*` version and optional arguments.